# Alice and Bob are playing a game. She hides behind her back $5 \text{ or } $25.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, computer-science, linear-programming, game-theory

Alice and Bob are playing a game. She hides behind her back \$5 or \$25. Then he guesses which of the two it is. If he is correct, he wins the amount. Otherwise, he pays her \$15.

What is each player's best strategy, given that the other player knows that strategy?

Comment: In the case of the person guessing (Bob), think what he has to lose should he be wrong. He would have to pay 15 dollars either way. This is also assuming the chance of having either 5 or 25 dollars is equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find the Nash equilibrium.

Say $A$ hides the $5$ with probability $p$ and the $25$ with probability $1-p$.  We seek $p$ such that $B$ can't improve his chances by varying his strategy.

We compute:  if $B$ guesses $5$ always his expected return is $$5p-15(1-p)$$

If he always guesses $25$ then it is $$25(1-p)-15p$$ Setting these equal and solving for $p$ yields $p=\boxed {\frac 23}$.

Note 1:  $B's$ equilibrium strategy can be computed in the same way.  The equations are similar and it turns out that $B$ should guess $5$ with probability $q=\frac 23$.

Note 2:  with that choice, $B$'s expected return is $-1.\overline {66}$ regardless of his strategy.  Bob should decline to play.

Comment: If $p=1$, Bob's expected return is infinite.

Comment: @Jens  I am computing the expected return on a single round.

Comment: This does not find Bob's equilibrium strategy, but the same approach works.

Comment: I don't know any game theory, but I'm puzzled as what the justification for setting the two expressions equal to each other. I.e., why should the expected value for both extreme strategies result in an equilibrium when put equal to each other? Would you mind elaborating? Thanks very much.

Comment: @Lovsovs  Nash equilibrium isn't the same as "optimal", though people often confuse the two.  The N.E, is defined to be the state at which neither player can improve their expectation by modifying their strategy.  You can imagine why this is a natural notion for, say, economists.  It has the advantage of being stable (when, as here, it exists). Also, existence is guaranteed under pretty general assumptions.  Other states, with "better" expectations might exist, but they won't be stable.

Comment: @Lovsos  Was that clear enough?  Suppose that at the N.E. Bob had a higher expectation by betting $5$.  Then, of course, he should bet $5$ only.  But in that case, $A$ should only hide $25$...so that state couldn't have been stable, hence it couldn't have been the N.E.

Comment: @Lovsos  You might find [Braess' Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braess%27_paradox) interesting.  That's a good, simple, example of a situation in which the N.E. is not "optimal" in the intuitive sense of the word.  In that paradox, there is an unstable state in which all parties have a higher expectation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was looking more for a technical one (it's the equating the two expectations I don't understand), as I understand the concept of NE.. but perhaps I should just read up on it. :) Do you have any recommendations for non-formal, short introductions (that can get you started with computing stuff, not necessarily prove the grand theorems)? Thanks once again.

Comment: @Lovsovs  [Nash's thesis](http://rbsc.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/Non-Cooperative_Games_Nash.pdf) is great.  I can't find a copy of the Annals version (1951) online. The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium) outlines the standard fixed point theory arguments and includes a number of references.

Comment: @Lovsovs  Most of the references you'll find online are associated with economics...for a different angle, I recommend [this](https://www.amazon.com/Evolutionary-Dynamics-Exploring-Equations-Life/dp/0674023382/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1477826107&sr=8-1&keywords=evolutionary+dynamics).

Comment: @lulu Looks amazing (I'm kinda into biophysics, so this is great), thanks!